# ¿Se utiliza "cuatezón" literalmente o como insulto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico

[Cuatezón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BUGYsaN)

> 1. adj. *Méx.* Dicho de un animal: Que, debiendo tener cuernos por su especie, carece de ellos.

Solo he encontrado esta palabra una única vez, utilizada como insulto ("¡Ese guarda es un cuatezón!"), lo que me lleva a plantearme si es una palabra habitual o de poco uso, y si el uso como insulto es frecuente.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo menos en el centro de México, podría afirmar que no se usa coloquialmente. Jamás la he oido utilizada.

Answer (score 2):

En el "**Diccionario para un macuto**" de García Serrano aparece:

> Giraldo manejaba con astucia un insulto que desconcertaba mucho, sobre todo si no se tenía un diccionario a mano. Giraldo lo empleaba más con los amigos que con los enemigos, porque a la hora de homerizar prefería atenerse a las normas clásicas y no apartarse de ellas ni un tanto así. Si Giraldo pedía tabaco y no se lo daban, decía:
>   —Valiente cuatezón estás hecho.
>   Cuatezón era el que le molestaba el sueño, el que le birlaba el periódico, el que no se prestaba a alguno de sus caprichos, el productor de pequeñas contrariedades o simples molestias.